# Is it possible to define or limit a command line alias to only work in a particular directory?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I want to create an alias command that only works in the current directory

```
$ foo
BAR!!!
$ cd ..
$ foo
bash: foo: command not found
```

Is there a way to define local bash aliases that are not global?

Comment: Can you just write a function and let the function check the current directory and bail if it's not what it wanted?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115630/defining-aliases-for-a-certain-directory

Comment: You can actually cram it in the alias. e.g. `alias foo='[ "$PWD" = /wanted/path ] && do stuff...'` using a compound command.

Answer (score 2):

The alias itself can exit early if it is in the wrong directly, as suggested by David C. Rankin:

```
alias foo='[ "$PWD" = /correct/path ] && ...'
```

or you can leverage `PROMPT_COMMAND` to define and undefine your alias as you move in and out of the desired directory:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='if [ "$PWD" = /correct/path ]; then alias foo='...'; else unalias foo'
```

(Using `PROMPT_COMMAND` as a proxy for a change-directory hook assumes, as rici points out, that your shell will display a prompt after the `cd` command but before you try to use the new alias.)

Comment: The (ab)use of `PROMPT_COMMAND` might be the best but it will fail if if you write `cd /correct/path; foo`. I don't know if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a few years too late, but I just recently finished up a script that accomplishes just that. Check it out: [localalias](https://github.com/bbugyi200/localalias).

It allows you to create and use pseudo-aliases and functions that are local to the directory they are defined in. Perhaps the best part is that it accomplishes this without performing any dicey "source" commands. These solutions are easier and faster, but are a big security concern.

Here's a demo:

[image]

NOTE: This script is designed to work with Zsh, but changing it to work with Bash would be a very trivial process. In fact, I originally designed this script to work with Bash, but later switched my primary shell to Zsh. Only a few lines needed to be changed to get it working with Zsh. The reverse process would be just as simple.